# Getting email address, google ID, or general user info under SL4A

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I'd like to get information from one or more user-accounts on an Android phone, from SL4A (using Python). This will be coupled with a data-stream going to a server that will have already associated that ID with an account using federated login.

Does SL4A have access to a facade that exposes that information, or at least one that can challenge the user for a particular account?